# jQuery: Slide element from a position to a position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to use jQuery to move an object. I would like to animate this movement to move the element from its current vertical position to a new vertical position, as measured from the upper edge of its parent element.

To do this animation right now, I do the following:

```
var b = $(".another_object").position();
$(".object_to_move").animate({top:b.top},200);
```

This animates great, but the animation always has the object beginning at top of the parent (ie from top:0px;) to the desired location.

Does anyone know how I can alter this or use another function to slide from the current position to the desired one?

Comment: show some relevant code or fiddle so we can identify easily please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var b = $(".another_object").position();
$(".object_to_move").animate({top:"+" + b.top},200);
```

Prefix it with a plus, and it will start where it currently is.